# A reasonable multivariate regression error metric

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, error, measurement-error, multivariate-regression

How would you compare error metrics of a multiple output regression? Normalised mean square error for each variable? How about for the overall performance of the model, would you just take the mean value of the NMSE for each variable?

Answer (score 5):

Consider that you have `m` outputs. These outputs may be interpreted as a point in the `m` dimensional space. Then, for each training case, you can compute the distance between the output of the model and the target point in this space. Euclidean distance and cosine-similarity are two choices. Note that cosine-similarity is a similarity measure so you should consider `1-cos` as the distance measure.

On the other hand, if your `m` outputs are not so tightly related and you cannot consider them as a point in the `m` dimensional space, you can use the mean value of the NMSE.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the case where the outputs are not standardised and scaled ( I used a random forest model), should this be performed? Otherwise the my impression is the euclidean distance likely to be dominated by the outputs with a larger range?

Comment: You are right. Euclidean distance is not a good choice here, while cosine-similarity works well.